# How to disable time of the day in datetimepicker

Tags: html, datetime, datetimepicker

I am using `DateTimePicker` and I am trying to disable some specific time gap in one day.

For example, I want to disable the time between `06/27/2018 08:20` and `09:43`.
So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Boostraps DateTimePicker has disabledTimeIntervals option

Comment: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates